# Writing Arabic or Hebrew characters to IEx command prompt with the --WERL switch on Windows crashes intermittently

Tags: elixir, werl.exe

I have been battling with this issue for a while now.

Writing Arabic or Hebrew characters to IEx console on Windows (`IEx --werl -S mix`) crashes intermittently. If I click on debug and attach to a Visual Studio Session, I can click continue and it works...

Is there a permanent work around for this?

Please note, running the same code directly from the IEx command prompt without the `--WERL` switch gives no errors. This somehow points to **WERL** as the culprit here.

[image]

**My Setup:**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14316]
--------------------------------------

Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10]

Interactive Elixir (1.2.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>
```

Comment: Are you sure those characters are causing the crash? There seem to be more log entries after the one you've highlighted in red.

Comment: @Dogbert "intermittently" crashes. i removed the source of the characters and no more crashes

Comment: Are you running that via WSL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux or via a Windows prompt? I ask because I notice that's the Windows 10 build number that enabled WSL.

Comment: I just tried typing a string of hebrew characters into WERL and I didn't see an issue.  Add the detail of whether or not you're trying this under WSL and also your current code page (chcp from the command prompt will show you the active codepage) and that will put us in a better position to see if we can reproduce the issue or not.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, Windows 10.0.14316 is an insider fast track build. As such it's beta software and hence may have some bugs.  If you can reproduce this issue on a non-beta version of Windows then post that. Otherwise, I'd say you're sort of on your own on this issue since you're working with a beta version of Windows.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci have had same issues before moving to windows insider build please. It in now way makes a difference to the problem at hand

Comment: I am running directly from regular windows command prompt, I am not using the WSL features with Elixir yet.

Comment: 1.) See if you can reproduce this behavior in the werl shell without iex involved. This would demonstrate if the issue is present in Erlang or in Elixir. 2.) Identify specific Hebrew and/or Arabic characters which definitely cause the issue and share them. In order to try to reproduce the issue people need _exact_ details.

Comment: Wait a sec--if you're running werl.exe directly then elixir isn't even a factor. If you want to run iex with werl the command line is iex.bat --werl. If you're running werl.exe then Elixir isn't even a factor in this question.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci no, im using this: `IEx --werl -S mix`

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci i did mention that this happened intermittently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109853/discussion-between-onorio-catenacci-and-charleso).

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot this actually is a **WERL** issue. If I run the same code directly from the windows command line, omitting the --werl  command, it works fine.

Comment: `werl.exe` is not a useful tag